# Unable to save fitler video using GPUImageMovieWriter in swift

Tags: ios, swift, gpu, gpuimage

i have created video Filter demo using Gpuimage filter for apply filter to video. below is my code for brightness filter. video is saved sometime but most of the time movieWritter unable to complete finishRecording or completionBlock while moviefile complete processing. at the end app terminate due to high usage of CPU and Memory usage.

```
let finalpath = "(FileManager.default.finalCompositions)/composition(getTimeStamp).mp4"
let finalUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: finalpath)

let asset: AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(url: self.videoUrl!)
let asetTrack: AVAssetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]

self.exportedMovieFile = GPUImageMovie(url: self.videoUrl)
self.exportedMovieFile?.runBenchmark = true
self.exportedMovieFile?.playAtActualSpeed = false

var exportfilter = GPUImageBrightnessFilter()
exportfilter.brightness = 0.5
self.exportedMovieFile?.addTarget(exportfilter)

let videosize: CGSize = CGSize(width: asetTrack.naturalSize.width, height: asetTrack.naturalSize.height)
self.exportedMovieWritter = GPUImageMovieWriter(movieURL: finalUrl, size: videosize)

exportfilter.addTarget(self.exportedMovieWritter)

//Configure this for video from the movie file, where we want to preserve all video frames and audio samples
self.exportedMovieWritter?.shouldPassthroughAudio = true
if asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio).count > 0 {
self.exportedMovieFile?.audioEncodingTarget = self.exportedMovieWritter
}
else
{
self.exportedMovieFile?.audioEncodingTarget = nil
}

self.exportedMovieFile?.enableSynchronizedEncoding(using: self.exportedMovieWritter)

self.exportedMovieWritter!.startRecording()
self.exportedMovieFile?.startProcessing()

DispatchQueue.main.async {
self.timerProgress = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.3, target: self, selector:#selector(self.filterRetrievingProgress), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

self.exportedMovieWritter?.failureBlock = {(err) in
loggingPrint("Error :: (err?.localizedDescription)")
}

self.exportedMovieWritter?.completionBlock = {() -> Void in
exportfilter.removeTarget(self.exportedMovieWritter)

self.exportedMovieWritter?.finishRecording(completionHandler: {
self.timerProgress?.invalidate()
self.timerProgress = nil

self.exportedMovieFile?.removeAllTargets()
self.exportedMovieFile?.cancelProcessing()
self.exportedMovieFile = nil
DispatchQueue.main.async {

                let uploadViewController = UploadViewController.loadController()
                uploadViewController.isPhoto = false
                uploadViewController.videoUrl = finalUrl
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(uploadViewController, animated: true)

            }  
        })
}

@objc fileprivate func filterRetrievingProgress() {
loggingPrint("Progess :: (self.exportedMovieFile?.progress)")
}
```